# How to work with arduino softwareserial communication using HC-05?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, arduino-nano, softwareserial, hc-05

This is my first project using bluetooth module HC-05.i am using two of this module.one is with arduino nano(slave) and another one is with arduino uno(master).I have paired them through AT commands .
for testing,i was giving a pulse in pin 7 on nano.if there is a pulse,then slave will send character "1".if not then it will send "0".

in UNO there is an LED connected with pin 13.if master receives '1',then LED will on and if recieves '0',LED will remain off.
here is my source code ----------

slave code=>
[image]

master code=>
[image]

the Arduino IDE isn't showing any bug,but code is not working at all.though,i am giving pulse in pin 7 on NANO, the LED in pin 13 on UNO is remaining off.i am at aloss now.please help me as soon as possible..

Comment: Is copy pasting code really that hard?

Comment: sorry,I didn't get you.

Comment: sorry...the main code has now been attached.

Comment: Does `CTRL + C` and `CTRL + V` ring a bell?

Comment: bro,would you please give me any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put pictures of you code in a post again, makes life very difficult!

The problem is the first line of the slaves loop

```
loop()
{
    if (slave.available()>0)  // Here is the bug
....
```

So If the "slave" serial port has data available to read then write data.  The master never writes to the slave so the slave never has any data to write, so your slave never sends any data and your master never reads any data.

In short remove that line and it will work.

Comment: sorry,I'm new to this group.so i didn't know the rules.But ,it still is not working,though i have removed the line.now the indication LED on HC-05 is flashing very quickly.

Comment: arduino RX=>TX of hc-05 and arduino TX=>RX of hc-06 ........this connections are same for both master and slave...for your convenience i have added these information.

Comment: at last,fixed it

Comment: What fixed it?  If it was this please mark this as the answer to help others, if not answer the question yourself.